# Use FME to know if CAD file is 2D or 3D

Tags: fme-form, 3d, cad

I have CAD files from AutoCAD and from MicroStation. I need to know if it's 2D or 3D. I have FME at my disposal. How can I know if it's 2D or 3D in FME?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  What have you tried?  Please [edit] your question to include as much info as possible about what you've tried, as this helps potential answerers to narrow down possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Data Inspector I'd just query a feature and check the information panel. It will say 2D or 3D for the dimension:

[image]

If it's in a workspace itself, then try the DimensionExtractor transformer. That will return whether the features are 2D or 3D as an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

There is a thread on the Safe Software forums which [asks the same question](https://knowledge.safe.com/questions/2971/how-to-detect-if-a-cad-file-is-2d3d.html), with a response that suggests the following:

> 1. *Visual check - view data in Inspector in 3d - view data edge on (ie in elevation). You will see a long horizontal line if data is in 2d -
>      otherwise it's in 3d (or badly drawn 2d !!!)*
> 2. *Expose X,Y and Z attributes of all data. Test for any Z attribute not equal to 0 - if any Z attributes are not equal to 0 - data is
>      probably 3d. Strictly speaking, test to see if all data (nodes /
>      vertices) have the same Z value. Use a Statistics Calculator and a
>      GroupBy on the Z attribute. If you have 1 Z value (probably 0) - data
>      is 2d If you have >1 Z value - data is 3d or badly drawn 2d - see
>      visual check above.*

There is more information on that thread that may be of use to you as well.

Comment: @YayNoNo I noticed the Accepted Answer was removed from this answer - did you find that this didn't work for you?  Perhaps expand your question a bit more with the result of trying the suggestions in this answer and someone else may be able to offer another answer